# How to write INPUT REGISTERS using pymodbus for external Modbus client which will read them

Tags: python, modbus, plc, pymodbus

I have been tasked with implementing a pymodbus-based Modbus server. The server will run on a Linux machine like a Raspberry Pi or Up2 controller. It is expected to interface with a Modbus client which I have no control over. That external Modbus client is expecting to be able to read INPUT REGISTERS as well as holding registers served by my Modbus server.

I can set the values of the HOLDING registers that will be read by the external client.  I have been unable to set the values of the INPUT registers that the external client will read.  How does one do that?

I saw this post which asked a similar question but the question doesn't seem to ever have been answered:

[How to write to PLC input registers using pymodbus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31912493/how-to-write-to-plc-input-registers-using-pymodbus)

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: How are you setting the values of the HOLDING registers on your server?

Comment: I have another MB client calling the "write_register" method in pymodbus.client.sync. That seems to set the holding registers just fine.

Comment: In fact I was thinking that internal client of mine would be able to do all the work of a server.  The EXTERNAL client doesn't need to know.  Unfortunately the external client is looking to read both INPUT registers along with HOLDING registers. I know how to set the HOLDING registers but not the INPUT ones.

Comment: That's what I figured.  Modbus Input Registers are not "by design" meant to be written (externally).  They are meant to be used for read only values on the device.  For example the the value of a temperature sensor, an A/D conversion, the device "up time" in seconds, etc.

Comment: I have seen that from all the comments online, but there is SOME code setting those Input Register values.  For example on a PLC, there must be SOME code setting those register values.  If I want to implement a PLC-like device using Python how do I serve these Input Register values for some external client that wants to treat my device as if it were a PLC?

Comment: OK, sorry I can't help with that, I do a lot of Modbus, but I am not really familiar with pymodbus.  I would say that there must be a way of mapping variables and blocks of memory from your running pymodbus server application to the input registers you want to publish.

Comment: No worries. Thanks for trying. This seems to be a hard one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Marker and to all the examples online.  I finally got this working as I wanted.  Hope this helps someone else.

There were several gotchas I ran into:

1. I tried following examples I found online all of which used pymodbus.server.async instead of pymodbus.server.sync.  I found that I could not import pymodbus.server.async because "async" is a reserved word in Python3.7! (not in older versions of Python). Either way I wanted to use pymodbus.server.sync because I wanted to avoid importing twisted if at all possible. This server will have 1-3 clients connecting to it at the most.
2. All the examples showing an updating writer used "LoopingCall" from Twisted. I have no idea what Twisted is and didn't want to use it unless I had to. I was familiar with multiprocessing and threading. I was already launching the ModbusTcpServer in a process and was trying to create managed object(s) around the store / context so I could have a different Process doing the updating. But that didn't work: I'm guessing StartTcpServer doesn't like receiving managed objects(?) and I didn't want to delve into that function.
3. One of the examples commented that a Python thread could be used, and that solved it. I still have the ModbusTcpServer launched in a Process but right before I call "StartTcpServer" I kickoff a THREAD rather than a PROCESS with the updating writer.  Then I didn't need to put the store / context in managed object(s) since the Thread can see the same dataspace as the Process that kicked it off.  I just needed ANOTHER managed object to send messages into this Thread the way I was already used to doing with a Process.

Sooo...

First I had to do this:
    `from threading import Thread`

Then I kicked the following off in a Process as I'd done before, but RIGHT BEFORE calling StartTcpServer I kicked off the updating_writer Thread (all start_addr, init_val and num_addrs variables are set earlier).

```
discrete_inputs_obj = ModbusSequentialDataBlock(di_start_addr, [di_init_val]*di_num_addrs)
coils_obj = ModbusSequentialDataBlock(co_start_addr, [co_init_val]*co_num_addrs)
holding_regs_obj = ModbusSequentialDataBlock(hr_start_addr, [hr_init_val]*hr_num_addrs)
input_regs_obj = ModbusSequentialDataBlock(ir_start_addr, [ir_init_val]*ir_num_addrs)
mb_store = ModbusSlaveContext(di=discrete_inputs_obj, co=coils_obj, hr=holding_regs_obj, ir=input_regs_obj, zero_mode=True)
mb_context = ModbusServerContext(slaves=mb_store, single=True)

mb_store = ModbusSlaveContext(
    di=ModbusSequentialDataBlock(di_start_addr, [di_init_val]*di_num_addrs),
    co=ModbusSequentialDataBlock(co_start_addr, [co_init_val]*co_num_addrs),
    hr=ModbusSequentialDataBlock(hr_start_addr, [hr_init_val]*hr_num_addrs),
    ir=ModbusSequentialDataBlock(ir_start_addr, [ir_init_val]*ir_num_addrs))
mb_context = ModbusServerContext(slaves=mb_store, single=True)

updating_writer_cfg = {}
updating_writer_cfg["mb_context"] = mb_context
updating_writer_cfg["managed_obj"] = managed_obj    #For being able to send messages to this Thread

updating_writer_thread = Thread(target = updating_writer, args = [updating_writer_cfg])    # We need this to be a thread in this process so that they can share the same datastore
updating_writer_thread.start()
StartTcpServer(mb_context, address=("", port))
```

In the While loop of updating_writer I have code that polls the managed_obj to receive messages.  In adding the key bits of code in that loop are:

```
mb_context[0].setValues(4, addr_to_write, regs_to_write)
```

...where 4 is the write function, addr_to_write is the register address at which to start writing and regs_to_write is a list of register values...AND...

```
regs_to_read = mb_context[0].getValues(3, addr_to_read, num_regs_to_read)
```

...where 3 is the read function, addr_to_read is the register address at which to start reading.  regs_to_read will be a list of length num_regs_to_read.

Answer (score 0):

As I said, I am not familiar with python or pymodbus, but take a look at this example which is something like what I expected would exist: https://pymodbus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/example/updating_server.html

Four 100 "register" arrays are created as the data store.  I assume di=digital inputs, co=coils, hr=holding registers, ir=input registers

```
store = ModbusSlaveContext(
    di=ModbusSequentialDataBlock(0, [17]*100),
    co=ModbusSequentialDataBlock(0, [17]*100),
    hr=ModbusSequentialDataBlock(0, [17]*100),
    ir=ModbusSequentialDataBlock(0, [17]*100))
context = ModbusServerContext(slaves=store, single=True)
```

These values are then updated in "updating_writer(a)" which is called by the background thread.  It looks to me like it just adds 1 to each value every time it is called.  In a real world PLC, this function would probably read things like sensors, settings, and other operational/state/configuration data.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in getting back to this.  I had been using the example you suggested but I was trying to avoid using twisted (I'm using pymodbus.server.sync instead of pymodbus.server.async, so twisted is not used). I had been struggling to use one "Process" for the TcpServer and another "Process" to create the updating writer and it was not working. I tried to put the store and / or the context in a managed object to share with the updaing writer, but nothing worked. Finally I tried using a Thread spawned from the TcpServer Process and that worked!  Thanks again!